# calculate group by running total in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

**I HAVE SOME SAME SAMPLE DATA IN MY TABLE**

```
ID | HOUSENO | AREAR |  CURRENT | TOTAL_DEMAND | TOTAL_RECIVED  
----------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1/10/1  | 0     | 165     | 0             | 0 
2  | 1/10/1  | 0     | 165     | 0             | 0  
3  | 1/10/1  | 0     | 165     | 0             | 0  
4  | 1/10/1  | 0     | 165     | 0             | 0  
5  | 1/10/1  | 0     | 165     | 0             | 0  
6  | 1/10/1  | 0     | 165     | 0             | 0  
7  | 1/10/1  | 0     | 165     | 0             | 0  
8  | 1/10/1  | 0     | 165     | 0             | 0  
9  | 1/10/1  | 0     | 198     | 0             | 495  
10 | 1/10/1  | 0     | 198     | 0             | 231  
11 | 1/10/1  | 0     | 198     | 0             | 198  
12 | 1/10/1  | 0     | 198     | 0             | 415  
13 | 1/10/1  | 0     | 198     | 0             | 198  
14 | 1/10/1  | 0     | 198     | 0             | 0  
15 | 1/10/1  | 0     | 198     | 0             | 415  
16 | 1/10/1  | 0     | 198     | 0             | 198  
17 | 1/10/1  | 0     | 198     | 0             | 0  
18 | 1/10/2  | 0     | 165     | 0             | 0  
19 | 1/10/2  | 0     | 165     | 0             | 0  
20 | 1/10/2  | 0     | 165     | 0             | 0  
21 | 1/10/2  | 0     | 165     | 0             | 0  
22 | 1/10/2  | 0     | 165     | 0             | 0  
23 | 1/10/2  | 0     | 165     | 0             | 0  
24 | 1/10/2  | 0     | 165     | 0             | 0  
25 | 1/10/2  | 0     | 165     | 0             | 0  
26 | 1/10/2  | 0     | 198     | 0             | 495  
27 | 1/10/2  | 0     | 198     | 0             | 231  
28 | 1/10/2  | 0     | 198     | 0             | 198  
29 | 1/10/2  | 0     | 198     | 0             | 415  
30 | 1/10/2  | 0     | 198     | 0             | 198  
31 | 1/10/2  | 0     | 198     | 0             | 0  
32 | 1/10/2  | 0     | 198     | 0             | 415  
33 | 1/10/2  | 0     | 198     | 0             | 198  
34 | 1/10/2  | 0     | 198     | 0             | 0
```

---

**Desired Output**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ID   HOUSENO | AREAR    CURRENT  TOTAL_DEMAND   TOTAL_RECIVED   
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    1   | 1/10/1 | 0      | 165     | 165           | 0             
    2   | 1/10/1 | 165    | 165     | 330           | 0             
    3   | 1/10/1 | 330    | 165     | 495           | 0             
    4   | 1/10/1 | 495    | 165     | 660           | 0             
    5   | 1/10/1 | 660    | 165     | 825           | 0             
    6   | 1/10/1 | 825    | 165     | 990           | 0             
    7   | 1/10/1 | 990    | 165     | 1155          | 0             
    8   | 1/10/1 | 1155   | 165     | 1320          |               
    9   | 1/10/1 | 1320   | 198     | 1518          | 495           
    10  | 1/10/1 | 1023   | 198     | 1221          | 231           
    11  | 1/10/1 | 990    | 198     | 1188          | 198           
    12  | 1/10/1 | 990    | 198     | 1188          | 415           
    13  | 1/10/1 | 773    | 198     | 971           | 198           
    14  | 1/10/1 | 773    | 198     | 971           | 0             
    15  | 1/10/1 | 971    | 198     | 1169          | 415           
    16  | 1/10/1 | 754    | 198     | 952           | 198           
    17  | 1/10/1 | 754    | 198     | 952           | 0             
    18  | 1/10/2 | 0      | 165     | 165           | 0             
    19  | 1/10/2 | 165    | 165     | 330           | 0             
    20  | 1/10/2 | 330    | 165     | 495           | 0             
    21  | 1/10/2 | 495    | 165     | 660           | 0             
    22  | 1/10/2 | 660    | 165     | 825           | 0             
    23  | 1/10/2 | 825    | 165     | 990           | 0             
    24  | 1/10/2 | 990    | 165     | 1155          | 0             
    25  | 1/10/2 | 1155   | 165     | 1320          | 0             
    26  | 1/10/2 | 1320   | 198     | 1518          | 495           
    27  | 1/10/2 | 1023   | 198     | 1221          | 231           
    28  | 1/10/2 | 990    | 198     | 1188          | 198           
    29  | 1/10/2 | 990    | 198     | 1188          | 415           
    30  | 1/10/2 | 773    | 198     | 971           | 198           
    31  | 1/10/2 | 773    | 198     | 971           | 0             
    32  | 1/10/2 | 971    | 198     | 1169          | 415           
    33  | 1/10/2 | 754    | 198     | 952           | 198           
    34  | 1/10/2 | 754    | 198     | 952           | 0
```

**Calculations :**

```
TOTAL_DEMAND = Arear + Current
```

DDL Script for the above.

```
DECLARE   @mytable TABLE (
   id             INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,houseno        VARCHAR(20) 
  ,arear          NUMERIC(18,3) 
  ,[CURRENT]         NUMERIC(18,3) 
  ,total_demand    NUMERIC(18,3) 
  ,total_received  NUMERIC(18,3) 
);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (1,'1/10/1',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (2,'1/10/1',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (3,'1/10/1',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (4,'1/10/1',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (5,'1/10/1',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (6,'1/10/1',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (7,'1/10/1',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (8,'1/10/1',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (9,'1/10/1',0,198,0,495);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (10,'1/10/1',0,198,0,231);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (11,'1/10/1',0,198,0,198);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (12,'1/10/1',0,198,0,415);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (13,'1/10/1',0,198,0,198);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (14,'1/10/1',0,198,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (15,'1/10/1',0,198,0,415);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (16,'1/10/1',0,198,0,198);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (17,'1/10/1',0,198,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (18,'1/10/2',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (19,'1/10/2',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (20,'1/10/2',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (21,'1/10/2',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (22,'1/10/2',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (23,'1/10/2',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (24,'1/10/2',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (25,'1/10/2',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (26,'1/10/2',0,198,0,495);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (27,'1/10/2',0,198,0,231);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (28,'1/10/2',0,198,0,198);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (29,'1/10/2',0,198,0,415);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (30,'1/10/2',0,198,0,198);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (31,'1/10/2',0,198,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (32,'1/10/2',0,198,0,415);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (33,'1/10/2',0,198,0,198);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (34,'1/10/2',0,198,0,0);
```

Please help...

Comment: is the order of transactions is based on the ID column?

Comment: based on ID and HouseNo

Comment: And why is the `TOTAL_DEMAND` reduced at some point? Could you please give a clear explanation of what you are expecting for all columns?

Comment: OK LET ME EXPLAIN...   
-------------------------------------------------
Check Calculation From Id == 9   
In This Row Total_Demand = 1518 And Total_Received = 495   
Than In Row  where id =10   
Arear is Total_Demand-TotalReceived = 1023   
And After That Total Demand  Is 1023 +198 = 1221   

Thanks

Comment: Please do not use ALL CAPS. That's considered as shouting. What's more, please edit the question itself, comments are hard to read as the space is small and there are no line breaks.

Comment: How is arear 0 in 18th column?

Comment: FROM 18TH TO 34 HOUSE NO IS DIFFERENT

Comment: It looks like your calculations are actually: `arear` = `0` for first entry for house #, `total_demand - total_received` (both from previous row) for subsequent entries; `total_demand` = `arear + Current` (from current row)

Comment: Also: If row 35 was `houseno` "1/10/1" again, should it treat that as a first entry (`arear` = `0`), or continue from where it left off, treating the row with `id` = 17 as the previous row? If the later, the sort order should be stated as `houseno`, `id`; the order is important.

Answer (score 1):

The following example uses a recursive Common Table Expression.  Recursive CTE's take a bit of analysis to understand what going on, so you may have to study it for a bit.  Based on your sample data, it does return your desired results. I have no idea what the performance would be on a large set of data.  Larger sets of data would require modification to the `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 100)` at the bottom of the query.

```
set nocount on 
DECLARE   @mytable TABLE (
   id             INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,houseno        VARCHAR(20)
  ,arear          NUMERIC(18,3)
  ,[CURRENT]         NUMERIC(18,3)
  ,total_demand    NUMERIC(18,3)
  ,total_received  NUMERIC(18,3)
);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (1,'1/10/1',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (2,'1/10/1',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (3,'1/10/1',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (4,'1/10/1',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (5,'1/10/1',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (6,'1/10/1',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (7,'1/10/1',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (8,'1/10/1',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (9,'1/10/1',0,198,0,495);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (10,'1/10/1',0,198,0,231);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (11,'1/10/1',0,198,0,198);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (12,'1/10/1',0,198,0,415);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (13,'1/10/1',0,198,0,198);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (14,'1/10/1',0,198,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (15,'1/10/1',0,198,0,415);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (16,'1/10/1',0,198,0,198);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (17,'1/10/1',0,198,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (18,'1/10/2',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (19,'1/10/2',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (20,'1/10/2',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (21,'1/10/2',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (22,'1/10/2',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (23,'1/10/2',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (24,'1/10/2',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (25,'1/10/2',0,165,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (26,'1/10/2',0,198,0,495);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (27,'1/10/2',0,198,0,231);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (28,'1/10/2',0,198,0,198);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (29,'1/10/2',0,198,0,415);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (30,'1/10/2',0,198,0,198);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (31,'1/10/2',0,198,0,0);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (32,'1/10/2',0,198,0,415);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (33,'1/10/2',0,198,0,198);
INSERT INTO @mytable(id,houseno,arear,[CURRENT],total_demand,total_received) VALUES (34,'1/10/2',0,198,0,0);

;

--cte to convert numeric to int
WITH x
AS (
    --recursive cte anchor row
    SELECT id
        ,houseno
        ,arear
        ,[current]
        ,convert(NUMERIC(18, 3), arear + [current]) AS total_demand
        ,total_received
        ,convert(NUMERIC(18, 3), arear + [current]) AS ArearForward
    FROM @mytable
    WHERE id = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT y.id
        ,y.houseno
        --if houseno changes use the current arear else use ArearForward
        ,convert(NUMERIC(18, 3), CASE 
                WHEN x.houseno <> y.houseno
                    THEN y.arear
                ELSE x.ArearForward
                END)
        ,y.[current]
        --if houseno changes, total_demand = arear + [current], else ArearForward + [current]
        ,convert(NUMERIC(18, 3), CASE 
                WHEN x.houseno <> y.houseno
                    THEN y.arear + y.[current]
                ELSE x.ArearForward + y.[current]
                END) AS total_demand
        ,y.total_received
        --if houseno changes, ArearForward = arear + [current], else ArearForward + [current] - total_received
        ,convert(NUMERIC(18, 3), CASE 
                WHEN x.houseno <> y.houseno
                    THEN y.arear + y.[current]
                ELSE x.ArearForward + y.[current] - y.total_received
                END) AS ArearForward
    FROM x
    INNER JOIN @mytable AS y ON y.id = x.id + 1
    )
SELECT id
    ,houseno
    ,arear
    ,[current]
    ,total_demand
    ,total_received
FROM x
ORDER BY id
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 100);
```

---

```
| id | houseno | arear    | current | total_demand | total_received |
|----|---------|----------|---------|--------------|----------------|
| 1  | 1/10/1  | 0.000    | 165.000 | 165.000      | 0.000          |
| 2  | 1/10/1  | 165.000  | 165.000 | 330.000      | 0.000          |
| 3  | 1/10/1  | 330.000  | 165.000 | 495.000      | 0.000          |
| 4  | 1/10/1  | 495.000  | 165.000 | 660.000      | 0.000          |
| 5  | 1/10/1  | 660.000  | 165.000 | 825.000      | 0.000          |
| 6  | 1/10/1  | 825.000  | 165.000 | 990.000      | 0.000          |
| 7  | 1/10/1  | 990.000  | 165.000 | 1155.000     | 0.000          |
| 8  | 1/10/1  | 1155.000 | 165.000 | 1320.000     | 0.000          |
| 9  | 1/10/1  | 1320.000 | 198.000 | 1518.000     | 495.000        |
| 10 | 1/10/1  | 1023.000 | 198.000 | 1221.000     | 231.000        |
| 11 | 1/10/1  | 990.000  | 198.000 | 1188.000     | 198.000        |
| 12 | 1/10/1  | 990.000  | 198.000 | 1188.000     | 415.000        |
| 13 | 1/10/1  | 773.000  | 198.000 | 971.000      | 198.000        |
| 14 | 1/10/1  | 773.000  | 198.000 | 971.000      | 0.000          |
| 15 | 1/10/1  | 971.000  | 198.000 | 1169.000     | 415.000        |
| 16 | 1/10/1  | 754.000  | 198.000 | 952.000      | 198.000        |
| 17 | 1/10/1  | 754.000  | 198.000 | 952.000      | 0.000          |
| 18 | 1/10/2  | 0.000    | 165.000 | 165.000      | 0.000          |
| 19 | 1/10/2  | 165.000  | 165.000 | 330.000      | 0.000          |
| 20 | 1/10/2  | 330.000  | 165.000 | 495.000      | 0.000          |
| 21 | 1/10/2  | 495.000  | 165.000 | 660.000      | 0.000          |
| 22 | 1/10/2  | 660.000  | 165.000 | 825.000      | 0.000          |
| 23 | 1/10/2  | 825.000  | 165.000 | 990.000      | 0.000          |
| 24 | 1/10/2  | 990.000  | 165.000 | 1155.000     | 0.000          |
| 25 | 1/10/2  | 1155.000 | 165.000 | 1320.000     | 0.000          |
| 26 | 1/10/2  | 1320.000 | 198.000 | 1518.000     | 495.000        |
| 27 | 1/10/2  | 1023.000 | 198.000 | 1221.000     | 231.000        |
| 28 | 1/10/2  | 990.000  | 198.000 | 1188.000     | 198.000        |
| 29 | 1/10/2  | 990.000  | 198.000 | 1188.000     | 415.000        |
| 30 | 1/10/2  | 773.000  | 198.000 | 971.000      | 198.000        |
| 31 | 1/10/2  | 773.000  | 198.000 | 971.000      | 0.000          |
| 32 | 1/10/2  | 971.000  | 198.000 | 1169.000     | 415.000        |
| 33 | 1/10/2  | 754.000  | 198.000 | 952.000      | 198.000        |
| 34 | 1/10/2  | 754.000  | 198.000 | 952.000      | 0.000          |
```

Comment: hi scott  Hodgin,
Very First Thanks For Helping Me.
Data is now coming as per my desired output but only one thing is left 
You convert decimal values to Integer this is not ok for me because most of values are in decimal 
so i request you to please do only this change for me 
before asking to you i tried to convert int to decimal but it gives error
Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 48
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "arear" of recursive query "x".

Comment: @SavitaVerma - I've updated my example to keep the numeric (18,3) data types throughout the calculations.